# boost access float array from JSON data

Tags: json, boost-propertytree

I have some JSON data collected via boost and I can not work out how to access some of the data that is in an array:

JSON data : {"dvm_gnd": {"num" : 4, "value": [1,2,3,4]}, "xx_gn" : {"num : 1, "value": 5}}

I can easily get the "num" and single "value" (5) out using:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt) {
  float value = v.second.get<float>("value")
}
```

However I have no idea how to access the elements of the array out? What does the ptree.get() return?

Thanks

Ross

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("dvm_gnd.value")) {
  float value = v.second.data();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've moved on by now, but in case someone else comes across this, ptree puts those array values as children with a blank name, so the code you want looks something like:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("dvm_gnd.value")) {
  float value = v.second.get<float>("");
}
```

Or you can use the optional or default value version of get